# How to determine NLog date format?

Tags: c#, .net, nlog

Using the configuration I have an entry:

```
<target name="logfile" xsi:type="File"
  fileName="${basedir}\Logs\${shortdate}\Log_${var:dbname}.txt  />
```

This creates the log file(s) in a directory e.g.

```
Log\2020-08-31
```

How can I determine that `shortdate` format is actually `"yyyy-MM-dd"`?
Can I assume `shortdate` will **always** have that format?

Using NLog 4.7.4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the documentation the ${shordate} is in the format yyyy-MM-dd.

https://nlog-project.org/config/?tab=layout-renderers&search=shortdate

Please check the below if you would like use custom layout renderers.

[Custom date format with NLog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29222410/custom-date-format-with-nlog)